# Post Error - Node.JS (Payload)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, mongoose

Today when require a post in my server (Local) with a base64 image are returning this error:
Frontend are using AngularJS
Backend using MongoDB,Node.JS,Mongoose and NodeRestFULL

[Front](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5qsr.jpg)

[Error backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqgD8.jpg)

Here my server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const server = express();
//transform params to int
const queryParser = require('express-query-int')
//const allowCors = require('./cors')
server.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,PATCH,DELETE')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next()
})

server.use(queryParser())
server.use(bodyParse.text({type:'*/*'}))
server.use(bodyParse.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}))
server.use(bodyParse.json({type:'json/*', limit: '50mb'}))
//server.use(bodyParse.urlencoded({limit: '50mb'}));

server.listen(port, function(){
    console.log(`BACKEND está rodando na porta ${port}`)
})

module.exports = server
```

loader.js

```
const server = require('./config/server')
require('./config/database')
require('./config/routes')(server)
```

Here my schema for mongodb

```
const restful = require('node-restful')
const mongoose = restful.mongoose

//Schema para os comprovantes
const reciboProventoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:  { type: String, required: true},
    month: { type: String, required: true},
    description: { type: String, required: true},
    imgBase: {type: String, required: true}
})

module.exports = restful.model('BillsPaysProv', reciboProventoSchema)
```

Here i'll make basic services

```
//Import schemas 
const BillsPaysProv = require('./billsProv')

//Create service to post a mensage contact
BillsPaysProv.methods(['get','put','post','delete'])
BillsPaysProv.updateOptions({new: true, runValidators: true})

module.exports = BillsPaysProv
```

Comment: Please post code as text, with propper layout, not in images.

Comment: edited with code (: srrys i'm new here